# Wrong magic bytes at the start in lib

Tags: 12.04, windows-7, virtualbox, dpkg

I was curious to know how this happened and how to correct it?

```
    Setting up gstreamer0.10-plugins-good (0.10.31-1ubuntu1.2) ...
dpkg: error processing gstreamer0.10-plugins-good (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script was killed by signal (Segmentation fault), core dumped
Setting up libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-quantal (9.0.3-0ubuntu0.4~precise1) ...
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXv.so.1 is not an ELF file - it has the wrong magic bytes at the start.

Aborted (core dumped)
dpkg: error processing libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-quantal (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 134
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libqt4-opengl:
 libqt4-opengl depends on libgl1-mesa-glx | libgl1; however:
  Package libgl1-mesa-glx is not installed.
  Package libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-quantal which provides libgl1-mesa-glx is not configured yet.
  Package libgl1 is not installed.
  Package libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-quantal which provides libgl1 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing libqt4-opengl (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libglu1-mesa:
 libglu1-mesa depends on libgl1-mesa-glx | libgl1; however:
  Package libgl1-mesa-glx is not installed.
  Package libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-quantal which provides libgl1-mesa-glx is not configured yet.
  Package libgl1 is not installed.
  Package libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-quantal which provides libgl1 is not configured yet.
dpkg: erNo apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
```

Everything I have installed through the terminal I get this at the end:
`E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`

I imagine this is where I am getting an error everytime I try to install something with `sudo apt-get whatever`.  My setup is Windows 7, Virtualbox, Ubuntu 12.04 x64.  I did install Guest Additions but I cant seem to figure out how to update this.  I **do** have root access.  I would like to learn why this wasn't installed, if it was a bad download copy and if I should delete the virtual session, download a new copy and start over again.  Any input on how I can learn how to correct this would be great or what could have caused this.

Comment: What does `file /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXv.so.1` say?

Comment: nothing it appears to be an archive